# Multi-inheritance, accessing an object from a parallel virtual class

Tags: c++

Look at the following class structure:

```
  D  D
  |  |
  C  C
  |  |
  T  T
  |  |
A–T1 T2–A
  |  |
  I  I
```

Where A is an abstract class and T1/T2 are classes which inherit from both A and T. I would like to know how I can access T from A (using a virtual function) so that I can use object A in a function that normally requires T. To be more exact, the function is of type `fct(D& d)` but works of course if the object is T as it inherits directly from D, which is not the case for A.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use multiple inheritance judiciously... Or not at all.

Comment: Wouldn't casting work here? Since T1/T2 is both A and T?

Comment: why would you access T from A in a fisrt place? T and A are not related, so accesing T from A is a bad idea. you can access both T and A from T1/T2, so T1/T2 can implement interface of T in terms of A.

Comment: If you have a reference `a` of type `A&` and you're sure that it represents either a `T1` or a `T2`, you can cast `a` to `T1&` or `T2&` (you can try various `dynamic_cast`), and then you'll get able to call `fct`. But as other have already mentioned, this smells bad design in the first place... Why not have an intermediate class `TX` that inherites from both `A` and `T`, and then `T1` and `T2` both inherits from `TX`, so you can use a `TX` in place of `A` in the above scenario.